# how to restart subprocess if it crashes?

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

I'm trying to restart a subprocess if it crashes, but somewhy this loop just doesn't work. I've been wondering if that's even possible?

```
def dont_stop(conv):
    try:
        subprocess.call(['python', 'main.py', str(conv)])
    except:
        dont_stop(conv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    proc = []
    for conv in range(3,8):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(name=f'p{conv}', target=dont_stop, args=(conv,))
        p.start()
        proc.append(p)
    for p in proc:
        p.join()
```

Comment: I would use a `Queue` and send information about success or failure to the main loop. Then the main loop would restart the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `subprocess.call` function doesn't raise an exception if the program it is running exits in a non-standard way. All it does is return the "return code" from the process you told it to run. That's usually `0` for a process that exits normally, and some other value for a program that crashes (the specific meanings of non-zero values vary between programs and OSs).

Here's a simple solution that replaces your recursive code with a loop that checks the return value of the subprocess:

```
def dont_stop(conv):
    retval = 1
    while retval != 0:      # a return value of zero indicates a normal exit
        retval = subprocess.call(['python', 'main.py', str(conv)])
```

An alternative approach is to stop using `subprocess.call` and use `subprocess.check_call` instead. That function checks the return code and raises an exception if it's not zero. While often that's what we'd prefer, it's actually a bit uglier here.

```
def dont_stop(conv):
    while True:
        try:
            subprocess.check_call(['python', 'main.py', str(conv)])
            break
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
            # do logging here?
            pass
```

Since the program you're running is also a Python program, you might consider importing it, rather than running it in a separate interpreter. That might let your `dont_stop` function directly interact with the `main.py` code, such as catching and logging exceptions. The details of that are much too dependent on the design of `main.py` and what it's supposed to be doing though, so I'm not going to show any suggested code for this approach.